# Ficheros que no se borran físicamente con python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Estoy ejecutando un script en python de manera operacional, es decir se ejecuta cada cierto tiempo, y actualiza unos ficheros, borra los antiguos y crea los nuevos, pero a la hora de borrar un directorio antiguo con `shutil.rmtree(path)`, si algún fichero de ese directorio está en uso por otro proceso, hace un borrado lógico pero no físico, es decir, los ficheros siguen ocupando espacio, al ejecutar el comando:

```
lsof +L1 |grep data
```

aparece algo así

```
java       7389   root  218r   REG  253,7    511060     0      83 /data/xxxx/xxx/xxx/a
xxx.nc (deleted)
```

Esto es un problema porque nos llena las particiones y para borrarlo lo único que hemos visto es matar el proceso de java, pero nos produce un reinicio en el servidor que no es viable.

¿hay alguna otra manera de eliminar estos ficheros?

Añado un ejemplo de uso

Creo que es más un tema de concepto que de código, el código de borrado no tiene más que un método en el que se le pasa el directorio a borrar

```
import shutil

def remove_old_dir(path):
    shutil.rmtree(path)
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Y dónde está el código? Sin ver el código, ¿cómo saber que pasa?. Por favor, publica un ejemplo completo y mínimo que muestre el problema en cuestión.

Comment: ¿Estás pidiendo cómo borrar ficheros que están en uso?¿En serio que te parece más "viable" y menos peligroso que reiniciar el proceso java? De todos modos, python ha hecho su labor de borrado. No liberarás el espacio hasta que java no cierre los ficheros que usa.

Comment: Son ficheros que ha cacheado pero no es capaz de liberar, no están en uso, reiniciar el proceso de java produce un reinicio de la aplicación que corre en tomcat y mata todos los procesos que se estén ejecutando, la aplicación que se ejecuta es thredds [Thredds](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/tds/current/). thredds es quien cachea los ficheros con el proceso de java

Comment: Thredds usa por defecto una caché de 32MB. Esos ficheros seguramente sólo puedan liberarse reniciando el contenedor tomcat o matando directamente los procesos java que los estén bloqueando.

Comment: Ahora mismo eso es lo que hacemos, cada 8 horas limpiamos, pero ahora hay una nueva aplicación que se puede tirar x horas ejecutando, cuando se mata el proceso de java, se reinicia el war de thredds y mata todos los procesos que se estén ejecutando, rompiendo todos los procesos, por eso estamos mirando si hay alguna manera alternativa de borrar los ficheros desde python para que no se queden en ese estado